# How to configure vcs trigger rule at Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I use TC 8.1 and i want to config vcs rule to run build only if check - in where made on specific folder under the root.

I try to use vcs rule with no sucess about the correct syntax and paramter i need.

I use TFS source control.

Thank!

Comment: What syntax have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this lies in the VCS settings page.

1) Go to the VCS settings page for your project.
2) Choose edit root
3) About 3/4 down the page there is a setting for "root"

Set this to the path of your project in TFS i.e.

```
$/something/else/SomeSLNFolder
```

Then any VCS triggers will be constrained to checkins under that root path